# Identify remote session in windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-xp

Are there any ways to use C++ to identify which session is remote session on windows XP?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the current session in which your process is running is inside a remote session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `WTSIsRemoteSession()`,see the [reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationa)

Then choose the type of information for "[_WTS_INFO_CLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wtsapi32/ne-wtsapi32-wts_info_class) WTSInfoClass ", set `WTSInfoClass = WTSIsRemoteSession`

> Determines whether the current session is a remote session. The
>   WTSQuerySessionInformation function returns a value of TRUE to
>   indicate that the current session is a remote session, and FALSE to
>   indicate that the current session is a local session. This value can
>   only be used for the local machine, so the hServer parameter of the
>   WTSQuerySessionInformation function must contain
>   WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE.

Comment: In MSDN, this function's requirement is "Minimum supported client Windows Vista", but now I know that it still can work in Windows XP. Thanks.